# How to display a non-interactive message on a JFrame?

Tags: java

I'm writing this code here:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import javax.swing.JTextArea;

import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class FirstJavaClass {
public static void main(String[] args) {
try {
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
} catch (Exception evt) {}

JFrame f = new JFrame("Example");
f.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
f.getContentPane().add(new JTextArea("Text Area\nText Area", 18,18));

f.pack();
f.setVisible(true); 

   }
}
```

When I run it I get a window with the "text area" printed on but I can type on it. How can I prevent the user from modifying whatever message I wrote there?

Comment: Here's a tutorial with your answer: http://www.java-examples.com/create-read-only-jtextfield-example

Answer (score 1):

You could use JLabel as output -only text field.

Or if you insist on using JTextArea, you can set the editable -property as false.

```
    JTextArea area = new JTextArea("Text Area\nText Area", 18,18);
    area.setEditable(false);
    f.getContentPane().add(area);
```